# Why does my 'position: absolute' stick only to the first block?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a several-block webpage, where `<section>` tags represent blocks. I want a message to show at the bottom of the second block, but it keeps showing up at the bottom of the first one.

```css
.block {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.secondBlock {
  background-color: #010c2d;
}

.sticky {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3em;
  bottom: 2em;
  /* or 2vh - it doesn't matter */
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  color: #ddd;
}

.left-wrapper {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-left: 4em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  width: 55vw;
}
```

```html
</section>

<section class="block secondBlock">

  <div class="left-wrapper">
    <h1 class="heading aboutHeading">About me</h1>
    <p class="sticky">
      my projects &downarrow;
    </p>
  </div>

</section>

<section class="block thirdBlock">
```

What it shows me (black is the first block):

[image]

Though, when I use the same code for the first block, everything works fine. It shows the text where I want it to be. But when it comes to the second one, I get this problem.

Comment: Hard to know precisely what you're trying to do without seeing more of the code for context, but I believe you want a `position: relative;` rule, probably in `.block`

Comment: Wow, cool, that actually worked! I'm not that skillful at frontend, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand @motto 's solution, `absolute` positioned elements properties, like *right, left, top and bottom* are related to the ***first parent element with `relative` position property*** if it does not exists will refer to the document.

So use `position: relative` on the parent element that you want to be the anchor for your absolute positioned element.